# SQL Substring variable text within URL string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to parse information from a column of URLS in SQL Server 2012

The basic structure is

```
http://www.domainsomething.com/?test/campaign=abc&kwd=jdc ftp&catgory=brnd
```

Where I need to grab the parameters from the `kwd=` value. In the above example, it would be the '`jdc ftp`', but this would might be different for all the URLs in my column.  I've tried `CHARINDEX` and `LEN`, but I can't seem to put the syntax together correctly.

Comment: Show your "failing" code

Comment: This is really not something you want to be doing in SQL Server.  In a good design the client application could be anything, not just a web application.  You should not have to go down to the guts of HTML in your SQL code - separate it out into the parameters you expect and let the calling code sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @URL varchar(100) = 'http://www.domainsomething.com/?test/campaign=abc&kwd=jdc ftp&catgory=brnd'

SELECT SUBSTRING(
       @URL, 
       CHARINDEX('kwd=', @URL)+4, 
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&', @URL, CHARINDEX('kwd=', @URL)+5) > 0 THEN
       CHARINDEX('&', @URL, CHARINDEX('kwd=', @URL)+5)
        - (CHARINDEX('kwd=', @URL)+4)
       ELSE
          LEN(@URL)
       END
       )
```

This will also handle cases when the kwd is the last or first variable in the query string.

You can play with it yourself in [this sql fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1199)

Comment: I suggest `CHARINDEX('kwd=', @URL + 'kwd=')+4` to return `''` for a URL that has no `kwd=` ;)

Comment: @shA.t That might be a good idea, but it is dependent on business logic. I was going on the assumption that a url without a kwd parameter should raise an error.